# How do I convert an image back from its binary data stored in a database?

Tags: c#, .net, database, blob, handler

I have a little problem here.

On my page I use a asp:repeater to read out all the "Projects" from my database.
Now each project also contains two images (binary data) and I want to convert them back to images in a handler and use the handler file as the image reference.

I found this code on the web, I also know how it wokrs but I dont know how to use in with a handler:

```
public Byte[] Ret_image(Int32 id)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Project where Id=@id";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    Byte[] ar = (Byte[])(dr[1]);
    dr.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
    return ar;
}
```

I think this would probably work, all I need to do I think is to give the ID of each project, but I don't quite know how to implement this and I don't even know if the code above is correct.

Can anyone help me?

thanks in advance!

**[edit]**

How do I give the handler the IDs it needs?

```
<asp:Image ID="img" ImageUrl="Image.ashx" runat="server" Height="80" Width="75%" />
```

Or how can I get the correct IDs from within the handler?

**[EDIT 2]**

What am I doing wrong? The Images do not appear, But it doesn't say that it doesn't find them:

```
<asp:img class="icon-img icon-img_shadow" src="Image.ashx?ID=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.id") %>" alt="Icon" width="152" height="140" />
```

Code in handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["ID"]);

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(Ret_image(id));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
    while (byteSeq > 0)
    {
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
        byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
    }
}

public Byte[] Ret_image(Int32 id)
{
    SqlConnection sqlCn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=user;Password=pw");

    string qry = "SELECT * FROM Project WHERE imageid=@id";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, sqlCn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    sqlCn.Open();
    dr.Read();
    Byte[] ar = (Byte[])(dr[1]);
    dr.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
    sqlCn.Close();
    return ar;
}
```

Comment: It works but I don't know how. Use the debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an ashx page that you'll target as an image URL

Then you need to write the byte array as response stream in the ProcessRequest method inside that handler... Something like:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
strm = new MemoryStream(ar);   // ar here is your variable from Byte[] ar = (Byte[])(dr[1])
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
while (byteSeq > 0)
{
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
    byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks, So I get the byte array from the method in my question, then do this and then of course the handler returns the image or "is" the image.

But before I even get the byte array from the database I need the ID of the image as a parameter...How can I give the ID to the handler or get it from there?

Comment: You can pass the Id as part of the request (in the url you go to say yourHandler.ashx?ID=55) then you can get the image id from request for example: int id = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["ID"])

Comment: Could you help me one more time?
Could you have a look at my 2nd edit above and check what I'm doing wrong?!

Comment: You didn't say what's the error, but the first thing I notice is that you need to use single quotes in the src tag for image to avoid compilation error in your page src='Image.ashx?ID=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.id") %>'.

Comment: Well I don't get any errors...It should work with normal quotes as well, I once used a captcha handler as an image...that always worked.
I think I found the problem...As an ID I use GUIDs and I probably have to use as strings to compare?

Comment: When it comes to this part: `Byte[] ar = (Byte[])(dr[1]);`, I get following error message: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.`Can you help me?

Comment: It seems that the column returned with index 1 (second column returned) is a string, that's not the image you're looking for. Check the query you're executing.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `MemoryStream` class and pass the byte array as a constructor parameter:

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
 Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
 return returnImage;
```